# How do I get a GameObject to rotate and face away from a MouseClick location in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, coordinate-systems, mouse-position

So in my Unity exercise, I have to rotate a GameObject to face away from where I clicked my mouse. Also, I can only rotate around the Y-axis i.e. the GameObject is only allowed to rotate either purely to the right or purely to the left, and cannot tip towards the ground at any point. Also, I've got to do this without RayCasting (I've already done it WITH RayCasting, so as an exercise, I've got to do it without). Here's the code I've written after multiple attempts but it doesn't seem to be effective enough:

```
Vector3 clickLocation = Input.mousePosition;
Vector3 clickWorldLocation = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(clickLocation.x, clickLocation.y, transform.position.x)); //the transform.position.x is just to add some depth 
transform.LookAt(new Vector3(clickWorldLocation.x, transform.position.y, clickWorldLocation.z), Vector3.up);
```

This code works fine if my GameObject remains in its starting position, but fails if I move it to another location and attempt the same action. Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

First, call `Camera.main` as infrequently as you can, as [it uses an expensive operation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) (`FindGameObjectsWithTag`) and doesn't cache the result.

```
private Camera mainCamera;
void Awake() 
{
    mainCamera = Camera.main;
}
```

To answer your question, don't use `ScreenToWorldPoint` in this situation, because a depth isn't most easily calculated. You don't have anything meaningful to use for the z component, and `transform.position.x` makes no sense here.

Instead, create a `Plane` that you want to click into (such as the plane parallel to the view plane and intersecting the object), use `ScreenPointToRay` to turn the mouse position into a `Ray`, then find where the ray and plane intersect. **`Plane.Raycast` is much, much faster than a physics raycast.**  Then, find the direction from the mouse world position to the object, and use Quaternion.LookRotation to turn that direction into a rotation you can assign to the object's rotation:

```
Ray mouseRay = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Plane mousePlane = new Plane(mainCamera.transform.forward, transform.position);
float rayDistance;
if (mousePlane.Raycast(mouseRay, out rayDistance))
{
    Vector3 mouseWorldPos = mouseRay.GetPoint(rayDistance);

    // make the z component of mouseWorldPos the same as transform.position
    mouseWorldPos.z = transform.position.z;

    Vector3 awayFromMouseDir = transform.position - mouseWorldPos;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(awayFromMouseDir, Vector3.up);
}
```